# Angular $routeParams is empty

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a url that's getting passed into my Angular code via Rails. However, when I try to pick up a parameter in the url, it shows up as blank. Can anyone help me out?

Sample url: `http://localhost:3000/events/event1`

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/yG8wAZHhgPtH2PBFzql3?p=preview

Angular:

```
eventsApp = angular.module('EventsApp', ['ngRoute'])


eventsApp.config [
    '$routeProvider'
    '$locationProvider'
    ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
        $routeProvider.when '/events/:eventName',
            templateUrl: '../../views/events/events.html.erb'
            controller: 'EventsCtrl'            
        return
]

eventsApp.controller('EventsCtrl',  [ 
    '$scope'
    '$routeParams'
    ($scope, $routeParams) ->       
        console.log($routeParams.eventName) # shows up as undefined
        $scope.greeting = $routeParams.eventName
])
```

HTML:

events.html.erb

```
    <div>
        {{greeting}}
    </div>
```

application.html.erb (overall layout)

```
<div id="content" ng-app="EventsApp">
        <div ng-view></div>
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
```

Edit: As suggested, I've moved `ng-app` and `ng-view` into the layout and kept only the div inside events.html.erb

Comment: Try to make sure your controller works fine by logging some string. Once you are sure it works, you can debug the `$routeParams`

Answer (score 3):

If the bugs pointed by Karaxuna still giving you empty result, it might be because of the asynchronous operation of `$routeParams`

`$routeParams` usually takes some time to load. It is being loaded asynchronously. When you are trying to use it, it might not ready and still empty. One approach is, create event listener when the route is ready.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
  console.log($routeParams.eventName);
});
```

Comment: I've tried as you suggested, it also comes up as blank

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide plnkr?

Comment: I am not sure how to test @routeProvider in plnkr. I dont think this is the problem, but I think you have typo in it. Should not be no return statement for controller.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have included controller with `ng-controller` directive instead of `ng-view`. It must be like this:

```
<body ng-app="EventsApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

In `events.html.erb`:

```
<div>
    {{greeting}}
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my post with what I think you're saying - would you mind taking a look?

Comment: @Andrew no, `{{greeting}}` must be in partial view. So what does `ng-view` do? it looks on your routes and determines which controller and view shall be loaded inside element which has `ng-view` (div in this case).